# Android: onBindViewHolder can't cache images

Tags: android

I am trying to download images if they don't exist yet, and keep and re-use them if they've already been downloaded.

While downloading and displaying works, re-using them does not. It seems like `mValues` isn't the same `mValues` in different calls.

Here is my code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final TabFragment1.SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).title);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).description);

        if (holder.mThumbnail == null) {
            System.out.println("thumbnail null"); //NEVER gets called
        } else {
            if(mValues.get(position).thumbnailData!=null){
                System.out.println("thumbnailData contained"); //NEVER GETS CALLED, IT ALWAYS SEEMS TO BE NUL
                holder.mThumbnail.setImageDrawable(mValues.get(position).thumbnailData);
            } else {
                System.out.println("thumbnailData downloading"); //always happening
                try {
                    AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> execute = new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) holder.mThumbnail)
                            .execute(holder.mItem.thumbnailUrl);
                    mValues.get(position).thumbnailData = holder.mThumbnail.getDrawable();

                    if(mValues.get(position).thumbnailData!=null) {
                        System.out.println("is null"); //hardly ever gets printed 
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("is not null"); //always gets printed
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

SOLVED: my code was wrong. The thumbnail update didn't wait for the AsyncTask to finish and I messed up the if statement so it tricked me into thinking the "new" thumbnail worked. I put the thumbnail update into the AsyncTask and now it's working :)

Comment: Your if else statement, inside try catch has interchanged log statements...Here your if statement checks for (thumbnail !=null) but prints it as null if found true.... so my point here is, your thumbnail object is always null, as its value would depend upon completion of Asynctask you started just above it, hence you cannot access it just like that, because this downloading process will run on separate thread.

Comment: Hey mate, I am 4 seconds late haha I just realized this when going through the code again. I am probably calling it too early, yeah. Will update as soon as I figured something out.

Comment: Ok I got it working now. Let's be fair to your effort here, compose as answer and I will tick. Thanks bro

Comment: sure mate, glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if else statement, inside try catch has interchanged log statements...Here your if statement checks for (thumbnail !=null) but prints it as null if found true.... so my point here is, your thumbnail object is always null, as its value would depend upon completion of Asynctask you started just above it, hence you cannot access it just like that, because this downloading process will run on separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for android, that will cache images and other cool things for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any good Image loading library like [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
 or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

You can also try  `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` on your recycler view.